# NSTableView with expandable/collapsable groups using Core Data & Cocoa Bindings

Tags: cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I have a data model stored in **core data** that is basically an array of items with a date.
They are currently displayed in a `NSTableView` using **cocoa bindings** via a `NSArrayController`.

What I'm trying to achieve, is to have the items grouped by months. Something like this

**August 2019** // can be collapsed

2019-08-05 ...

2019-08-04 ...

2019-08-01 ...

**> July 2019** // can be expanded

**June 2019** // can be expanded

2019-06-30 ...

2019-06-22 ...

...etc

I found two leads for this :

- NSOutlineView but it seems that it must be bound to a `TreeController`, and I'm not sure I should dive into this
- Use `NSTableView` `tableView:isGroupRow:`

What should I do to achieve this goal?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like an `NSOutlineView` to me! Using a tree controller *can* be a tad bit more complicated because at some of lower levels you end up dealing with "proxy node" objects (because Cocoa has no native "tree" collection class to map to). But learning `NSTreeController` is going to be a lot easier than trying to reinvent `NSOutlineView`. (As an alternative, you could consider using the traditional `NSOutlineViewDataSource` instead of bindings ... but only if you're absolutely terrified of `NSTreeController`.)

Comment: Thanks! And how should I manage the grouping by month with Core Data? I'm being quite confused about it.

Comment: I don't use Core Data, so I can't speak to that, but your tree will ultimately need to be constructed of "month" nodes, with each individual date a child of its month node. How to map your Core Data array into a tree sounds like a really good question for stack overflow ;)

Comment: Thanks! I found my way around with an Entity "Month" in Core Data that I shall manage in the code. I'll post an answer when everything gets crystal clear to me :-).

Comment: `NSTreeController` in Entity Mode has some issues.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Thanks

Comment: `NSTreeController` has one `childrenKeyPath` for all entities and sometimes the managed objects are released too late.